# Laravel - Cross Database Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I just learned Laravel, and I'm trying to create my own project. And now I have a challenge.

I have 3 tables. 2 tables in database A and 1 table in database B.

*The table in database B is not editable.*

**Table schema**

```
1. conn1.Db_A.app_schedules
 id  | name    | in    | out   
--------------------------------
  1  | 7AM-7PM | 07:00 | 19:00 


2. conn1.Db_A.app_schedule_schedule
 app_schedule_id | schedule_id | name
----------------------------------------------------
     1           |      5      | Long Shift
     1           |     32      | Long Morning Shift


3. conn2.Db_B.schedule
 idschedule | schedulename
----------------------------------------------------
     5      | Long Shift
    32      | Long Morning Shift
```

**Model AppSchedule.php**

```
class AppSchedule extends Model
{
    //
    protected $connection = 'conn1';
    protected $table = 'app_schedules';

    protected $fillable = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'name',
        'in',
        'out',
        'remarks',
    ];

    public function schedules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Schedule::class)->withPivot('schedule_id', 'name');
    }
}
```

**Model Schedule.php**

```
class Schedule extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'conn1';
    protected $table = 'app_schedule_schedule';

    public function appSchedules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(AppSchedules::class)->withPivot('schedule_id', 'name');
    }
}
```

**Model MainSchedule.php**

```
class MainSchedule extends Model
{
    //
    protected $connection = 'conn2';
    protected $table = 'schedule';
}
```

**Controller AppSchedulesController.php**

```
class AppSchedulesController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        //
        $schedules = MainSchedule::all();
        return view('admin.schedules.create')->with('schedules', $schedules);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $appschedule = AppSchedule::create($request->all());

        $mainScheIds = $request->input('mainScheIds', []);
        for($mainScheId=0; $mainScheId < count($mainScheIds); $mainScheId++){
            if($mainScheIds[$mainScheId] != '') {
                $appschedule->schedules()->attach($mainScheIds[$mainScheId], ['name' => MainSchedule::select('schedulename')->where('idschedule', $mainScheIds[$mainScheId])->value('schedulename')]);
            }
        }

        $appSchedules = AppSchedule::all();
        
        return view('admin.schedules.index')->with('appSchedules', $appSchedules);
    }
}
```

Now my challenge is when I want to retrieve a list in the index function.
I want to get a list like this:

```
 ID  | NAME    | IN    | OUT   ! MAIN SCHEDULE
-----------------------------------------------------------
  1  | 7AM-7PM | 07:00 | 19:00 | > 5 - Long Shift
     |         |       |       | > 32 - Long Morning Shift
```

But when I wrote this index function

```
public function index()
{
   $appSchedules = AppSchedule::with('schedules')->get();

   return view('admin.schedules.index')->with('appSchedules', $appSchedules);
}
```

I got an error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'app_schedule_schedule' (SQL: select `app_schedule_schedule`.*, `app_schedule_schedule`.`app_schedule_id` as `pivot_app_schedule_id`, `app_schedule_schedule`.`schedule_id` as `pivot_schedule_id`, `app_schedule_schedule`.`name` as `pivot_name` from `app_schedule_schedule` inner join `app_schedule_schedule` on `app_schedule_schedule`.`id` = `app_schedule_schedule`.`schedule_id` where `app_schedule_schedule`.`app_schedule_id` in (1))
```

I know that I have to provide a unique alias for each table. But I don't know how to do it and I want to get a result like that.

Is my relationship wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you forgot to config your pivot model. Take a look at this docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models
If that isn't enough, please comment back with your questions.

Comment: My Model Schedule has been updated. But I still get the same issue.

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Schedule extends Pivot
{
    protected $connection = 'conn1';
    protected $table = 'app_schedule_schedule';

    public function appSchedules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(AppSchedules::class)->withPivot('schedule_id', 'name');
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work

```
public function index()
{
   $appSchedules = AppSchedule::with(['schedules' => function ($query) {
                       $query->on('conn2');
                   }])->get();

   return view('admin.schedules.index')->with('appSchedules', $appSchedules);
}
```